# How to render a zip(made of 4 lists) and a dictionary on django template correctly?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to render some data I have been returned by a function on a table in django template. I am rendering two different lists, which have the same length, but when I render them in nested for loop, for some reason, I get extra copies of the inner loop.

```
  {% for d,t,r,y in open_route_info %}
            {% for k,v in open_trucks.items %}
                {% for i in v %}
                    k = {{ k }}
                    v = {{ v }}
                    i = {{ i }}
                    d = {{ d }}
                    t = {{ t }}
                    r = {{ r }}
                    y = {{ y }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

For ^ this i get output as :

> k = Dehradun-Gurgaon v = [{: []}] i = {: []} d = 0.279 t = 07 Hours 19 Minutes r = googlemaps.com y = May 23, 2019, 4:31 a.m. k = Delhi-Mumbai v = [{: []}] i = {: []} d = 0.279 t = 07 Hours 19 Minutes r = googlemaps.com y = May 23, 2019, 4:31 a.m. k = Dehradun-Gurgaon v = [{: []}] i = {: []} d = 1413.204 t = 29 Hours 48 Minutes r = googlemaps.com y = May 22, 2019, 6:03 a.m. k = Delhi-Mumbai v = [{: []}] i = {: []} d = 1413.204 t = 29 Hours 48 Minutes r = googlemaps.com y = May 22, 2019, 6:03 a.m.

Pardon the ugly data....

When I render them individually, I get the correct number of data, which is `2` in both cases. Here is the code for that :

```
        {% for d,t,r,y in open_route_info %}
                    d = {{ d }}
                    t = {{ t }}
                    r = {{ r }}
                    y = {{ y }}
        {% endfor %}
```

for this I get this output:

> d = 0.279 t = 07 Hours 20 Minutes r = googlemaps.com y = May 23, 2019, 4:32 a.m. d = 1413.204 t = 29 Hours 50 Minutes r = googlemaps.com y = May 22, 2019, 6:03 a.m.

As you can see, there are two of each of the values here, (d= date, t=time, r=routemap, y= ETA of the vehicle)

When rendering the `open_trucks` dictionary alone, outside of any nested loop, I used this :

```
   {% for k,v in open_trucks.items %}
                    {% for i in v %}
                        k = {{ k }}
                        v = {{ v }}
                        i = {{ i }}
                    {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
```

and output is :

> k = Dehradun-Gurgaon v = [{: []}] i = {: []} k = Delhi-Mumbai v = [{: []}] i = {: []}

Here too, as you can see there are only 2 elements. So the length of both elements are the same. But, when I use them nested, I get 4 results, out of which the last 2 are just copies of first.

This is my open_trucks dictionary:

```
{'Dehradun-Gurgaon': [{<Truckdb: Truckdb object (7)>: [<ItemBatch: A>]}], 
 'Delhi-Mumbai': [{<Truckdb: Truckdb object (7)>: [<ItemBatch: E>]}]}
```

This is my open_route_info which is a zip of 4 lists, each having 2 length:

```
(0.279, '07 Hours 02 Minutes', 'googlemaps.com', datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 23, 9, 31, 24, 538432))
(1413.204, '29 Hours 02 Minutes', 'googlemaps.com', datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 22, 11, 31, 59, 625005))
```

Am I getting wrong results because of not using the zip properly ?? Is there anything else I could be missing ?

---

Comment: I think that you have variable problem. Look in your code : You try to iterate with variable k v i for ex and you overwrite the value. Change the variable names in the for loop

Comment: @attin83 I am sorry, I do not understand. The value of `open_trucks` is itself a dictionary, hence I need to iterate over it, and for that I use `for i in v`. Is this the line you are referring to ?

Comment: You shouldn't use nested cycle. Pre-merge tables with data in Python.

Comment: @RohitKumar I am refering to the variable in the loop v = {{ v }}.

Comment: @attin83 How will changing that `{{v}}` to something else going to help me at all ?
@Vyacheslav So how else should I render the data ?

Comment: @RohitKumar One suggestion, maybe you can change the data structure(to display in template) in the view itself and then pass it to the template. It will be much easier/cleaner to perform this in the view itself

Comment: @rajkris I mean, I am trying to do the same thing really, but the thing is, I have two different kind of data elements to pass as arguments, and they are the same length and everything. So, I do not know what could be going wrong here.

Comment: What I actually meant is rather than nesting the loop in the template, it would be much easier for you to do this in the view and convert the data such that, you would be able to display it properly in the template with just one loop. This would make the template more readable.

Comment: And could you update the question with the open_route_info, data structure?

Comment: I saw that, this is a list of two dicts right?

Comment: @rajkris No, it is a simple list, having 4 elements.

Comment: @rajkris This is ``open_route_info = (1413.204, '29 Hours 02 Minutes', 'googlemaps.com', datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 22, 11, 31, 59, 625005))(0.279, '07 Hours 02 Minutes', 'googlemaps.com', datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 23, 9, 31, 24, 538432))``. What I wrote earlier was wrong.

Comment: @RohitKumar Even if it's a simple list you're trying to do the logic operation in the template. You should do it in background and display the result in the template. 
The template is here to display values not to do the business logic. 
There is an other way to process data in the templates : Look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: @attin83  What logic am I doing in the template ?? I am trying to just display them in a table. I have already done all my operations and finally been returned the zip and the dictionary. I do not know where you see me doing business logic in the template.